How to create a flow that checks the overlaping dates on records?
I have a custom object "Object1" with validation dates ValidStartDate and ValidEndDate.
Is it possible with a Flow to create a validation that would prevent a new record of Object1 to be created if its Validation period is overlaping with already created ones?
For example, I have a record with Start date 1.01.2024, end date 1.02.2024. I must not be able to create a record with Start date between 1.01.2024 and 1.02.2024. the Strt date of a new record should be avaliable starting  from 2.02.2024.
I tried to create a record triggered flow and with GetRecords to get all the records of Object1, then in a decision outcome try to campare the ValidStart of the new record and the ValidEnd from GetRecords, but it's not giving me the option to compare them, or I am not understanding how the GetRecord is working. I would then shoot an error, if there is an overlap. So, is it possible at all to do such a check with a flow, or is it possible only with a trigger?

Date range overlap is one of those problems that sounds easy, but is actually fairly difficult. I don't think you'd need a full-blown trigger to do this, but doing this in apex and providing an @AuraEnabled method so you can use it in your flow is going to ease the pain a bit (e.g. it's fairly simple to find the min start date and max end date in your records going through your flow, then use those to limit the number of existing records you'll query, making it more bulk-friendly).

@DerekF This is actually easier to solve in a Record-Triggered Flow than Apex, because flows handle the bulkification for you.

Don't query the entire database to find a value. That's going to run into governor limits. Instead, in your Get Records element, write your filter as follows:


End Date greater than $Record.Start Date AND

Start Date less than $Record.End Date AND

Id not equal to $Record.Id



A record that ends after the start date and starts before the end date overlaps.
I know it sounds too easy, but it really is. Let's make a truth table:



S1
E1
S2
E2
E2 > S1?
S2 < E1?
Overlap?
Note




1/1/2024
1/31/2024
1/1/2023
1/31/2023
No
Yes
No
Too early


1/1/2024
1/31/2024
1/1/2025
1/31/2025
Yes
No
No
Too late


1/1/2024
1/31/2024
12/15/2023
1/15/2024
Yes
Yes
Yes
Overlaps start


1/1/2024
1/31/2024
1/15/2024
2/15/2024
Yes
Yes
Yes
Overlaps end


1/1/2024
1/31/2024
12/15/2023
2/15/2024
Yes
Yes
Yes
Encloses range


1/1/2024
1/31/2024
1/10/2024
1/20/2024
Yes
Yes
Yes
Enclosed by range



S = Start, E = End
As you can see, there are six possible scenarios, and in all cases, both date conditions must be satisfied in order for the date to be considered overlapping.

Thanks, but I'm still a little confused. How then I compare the get results with the triggering record to validate if the record can be created? My main struggle is with the validation itself. After the Get element I placed a decision, where I wanted to place 2 outcomes: if the the start date of the triggering record is in the range of any of existing records, then I throw the error, end if not - nothing happenes. And the problem is that in the outcome condition If I place the Get element in resource I can't place the start date in the value and vice versa. How do I throw the validation error?

@SlavaBychenkoCT If you set the filter as I described, the Get Records element already contains the overlapping record, if one was found. Your Decision can be as simple as {!Get_Overlapped_Record.Id} Is Null $GlobalConstant.false. To show an error, use the Custom Error element.

Awsome, thanks! it works perfetly!
